# xpath copy expression in BPEL

Tags: xslt, xpath, bpel

I have problem in copying the output of a service response to the response message in BPEL .

The amount element has an attribute currency, How do I acheiev this ? All other copying seems to work fine, except copying an element to an attribute of another element.

The copy expression is below.

```
<copy>
        <from variable="InvokePersistence_insert_OutputVariable"
              part="ProBookingInitiationCollection"                 query="/ns3:ProBookingInitiationCollection/ns3:ProBookingInitiation/ns3:bookingDetail/ns3:isoCurrencyCd"/>
        <to variable="outputVariable" part="payload"
            query="/ns4:BookingConfirmation/ns4:amount/@ns4:currency"/>
      </copy>
```

The excerpts from xsd is below

```
 <xs:element name="amount">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Did you try `.../ns3:isoCurrencyCd/text()`?

Comment: @vanto Below is the error message. I tried /text() getting the same error.XPath query string returns zero node. "The assignment activity the destination node query returns a null node. The destination node data or the destination node in the XPath query was invalid. Check the destination note value at line number 198 in the BPEL source as BPEL4WS 1.1 specification, Section 14.3."

Comment: Sounds like a selection failure. Did you properly initialize the target elements and attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "outputVariable" output variable is properly initialised according to the schema and contains an attribute called "currency"